# How to select elements with more than one class in d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following problem with selected elements in d3 V4. To select below example in d3 v3:

```
class="y axis"
```

you have to call:

```
selectAll(".y.axis")
```

In v4 I can not selected this. Also

```
selectAll(".y").selectAll(".axis")
```

is not returning the appropriate elements.

Comment: Which v4 example are you referring here.

Comment: You have to set up an example demonstrating the behaviour. As far as I know there is absolutely **no** difference between v3, v4 or v5 regarding CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
let selection: any = d3.selectAll('.y.axis');
selection._groups[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in jsdom (PhantomJS) node module. I can't selected 
   selectAll(".y.axis"). 
Works only with one class
   selectAll(".y") 
or 
   selectAll(".axis")
But i think that this is matter to another thread.

Answer (score -1):

I apologize to everyone,it my mistake.
Example:
    selectAll(".y.axis")
works, but result are in selection._groups[0] section.

Comment: This is really bad usage of the API. `selection._groups` is a private field which should not be accessed directly. To me this looks like a XY-problem where your real issue is a variation of [*"D3 v4 - Accessing selection array and find corresponding element"*](/q/38702831).